# Initilaized variable in if statement, used later in code but says it isnt defined

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, initialization

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.lang.Math;

  public class pizzasMazboudi
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    double shapeOfPizza;
    double toppings;
    double pizzaCrust;
    double baseCost;
    double areaOfPizza;
    double numberOfToppings;
    final double COST_OF_ONE_TOPPING = 0.025;
    final double COST_OF_DOUGH = 0.019;
    final double COST_OF_SAUCE = 0.036;
    double diameterOfPizza;
    double lengthOfPizza;
    double widthOfPizza;
    double volumeOfDough;
    final double THIN_AND_CRISPY = .1;
    final double PAN = .5;
    final double CLASSIC_HAND_TOSSED = .25;
    final double TEXAS_TOAST = .9;
    double sizeOfCrust;
    double cheesyCrust;
    final double COST_OF_MATERIALS = .02;
    double numberOfPizzas;
    double costOfDelivery;
    double tax;
    double pizzaDelivery;
    final double PI = 3.14159;
    double typeOfCrust;
  double costOfCheesyCrust;
    double costOfPizzaDelivery;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Hello customer! Welcome to Guiseppi's Just Pizza!");
  System.out.println("Where we make the pizza just for you!");
  System.out.println("\n What kind of pizza do you want on" + 
                     " this beautiful day?");
  do
     {
     System.out.print("Press 1 for a square pizza,");  
     System.out.print(" or press 2 for a circle pizza: ");
     shapeOfPizza = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if(shapeOfPizza != 1 && shapeOfPizza != 2)
           {
           System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter 1 or 2");
           }
      }  
  while(shapeOfPizza != 1 && shapeOfPizza != 2);

  if(shapeOfPizza == 1)
     {
     System.out.println("And how big would you like your pizza?");

        do
           {
           System.out.print("Please enter the length of your pizza (under 60 inches: ");
           lengthOfPizza = keyboard.nextDouble();

              if(lengthOfPizza > 60 && lengthOfPizza < 0)
                 {
                 System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter a number between 0 and 60");
                 }
           }
        while(lengthOfPizza > 60 && lengthOfPizza < 0);

        do
           {   
           System.out.print("Please enter the width of your pizza: ");
           widthOfPizza = keyboard.nextDouble();

              if(widthOfPizza >60 && widthOfPizza <0)
                 {
                 System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter a number between 0 and 60.");
                 }
           }
        while(widthOfPizza > 60 && widthOfPizza < 0);

        areaOfPizza = lengthOfPizza * widthOfPizza;
        System.out.println("Your pizza is " + areaOfPizza + "inches large");
        sizeOfCrust = 2 * (lengthOfPizza + widthOfPizza);
     }   

  else if(shapeOfPizza == 2)
     {
     System.out.println("And how big would you like your pizza?");
     do
        {
        System.out.print("Please enter the diameter of your pizza: ");
        diameterOfPizza = keyboard.nextDouble();
           if(diameterOfPizza > 60 && diameterOfPizza <= 0)
              {
              System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter a number that is between 0 and 60.");
              }
        }
     while(diameterOfPizza > 60 && diameterOfPizza <= 0);

        sizeOfCrust = 2*PI*(diameterOfPizza/2);
        areaOfPizza = PI*((diameterOfPizza/2)*(diameterOfPizza/2));
        System.out.println("The area of your pizza is" + areaOfPizza + " inches large");
     }

  System.out.println("What type of crust would you like?");
  do
     {
     System.out.println("Enter 1 for Thin and Crispy, 2 for Pan,"); 
     System.out.println("3 for Classic Hand-Tossed, and 4 for Texas Toast");
     pizzaCrust = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if(pizzaCrust != 2 && pizzaCrust != 3 && pizzaCrust != 4)
           {
           System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4");
           }
     }
  while(pizzaCrust != 2 && pizzaCrust != 3 && pizzaCrust != 4);

  if(pizzaCrust == 1);
     {
     typeOfCrust = THIN_AND_CRISPY;
     }
  if(pizzaCrust == 2);
     {
     typeOfCrust = PAN;
     }
  if(pizzaCrust == 3);
     {
     typeOfCrust = CLASSIC_HAND_TOSSED;
     }
  if(pizzaCrust == 4);
     {
     typeOfCrust = TEXAS_TOAST;
     }

  if(pizzaCrust == 2 && pizzaCrust == 3 && pizzaCrust == 4)
     {
     System.out.println("Would you like to try our new cheesy crust today?");
     do
        {
        System.out.print("Enter 1 for yes or 2 for no");
        cheesyCrust = keyboard.nextDouble();
           if(cheesyCrust != 1 && cheesyCrust != 2)
              {
              System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter 1 or 2");
              }
        }
     while(cheesyCrust != 1 && cheesyCrust != 2);
     }
  System.out.println("Would you like any toppings today?");
  do
     {
     System.out.println("Enter 1 for toppings, enter 2 if you do not want toppings");
     toppings = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
        if(toppings != 1 && toppings !=2)
           {
           System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter 1 or 2");
           }
     }
  while(toppings != 1 && toppings !=2);

  if(toppings == 1)
     {
        do
           {
           System.out.println("How many toppings do you want? (10 toppings limit)");
           numberOfToppings = keyboard.nextDouble();
              if(numberOfToppings <=0 && numberOfToppings > 10)
                 {
                 System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter a number 1 through ten");
                 }
           }
        while(numberOfToppings <=0 && numberOfToppings > 10);
     }

  do
     {
     System.out.println("How many identical pizza's would you like?");
     numberOfPizzas = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if(numberOfPizzas <= 0)
           {
           System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter a number above 0");
           }
     }
  while(numberOfPizzas <= 0);

  System.out.println("Will you come pick up your order, or will you like delivery?");
  do
     {
     System.out.println("Enter 1 for delivery, enter 2 for pick-up");
     pizzaDelivery = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(pizzaDelivery != 1 && pizzaDelivery != 2)
           {
           System.out.println("That is an incorrect input, please enter a 1 or 2");
           }
     }
  while(pizzaDelivery != 1 && pizzaDelivery != 2);

  costOfCheesyCrust = sizeOfCrust * COST_OF_MATERIALS;
  volumeOfDough = typeOfCrust * areaOfPizza;
  baseCost = areaOfPizza * (COST_OF_SAUCE + numberOfToppings * COST_OF_ONE_TOPPING) + COST_OF_DOUGH * volumeOfDough;

  if(cheesyCrust == 1)
     {
     costOfCheesyCrust = sizeOfCrust * COST_OF_MATERIALS;
     baseCost = baseCost + costOfCheesyCrust;
     }
  if(pizzaDelivery == 1)
     {
     if(baseCost < 10)
        {
        costOfPizzaDelivery = 3.00;
        }
     else if(baseCost < 20 || baseCost >= 10)
        {
        costOfPizzaDelivery = 2.00;
        }
     else if(baseCost < 30 || baseCost >= 20)
        {
        costOfPizzaDelivery = 1.00;
        }
     else if(baseCost >= 30)
        {
        costOfPizzaDelivery = 0;
        }
     }
 }
```

}

So when i try to compile this, the variables numberOfTopping, areaOfPizza, and sizeOfCrust are all causes of errors because "they aren't initialized", but i have have defined them all as doubles and set numberOfTopping as keyboard.nextDouble and given the other 2 formulas, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: simply initialize them... put their default value when you declare them.. `double shapeOfPizza = 0.0;` do  it for all other local variable you have.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is correct.

`numberOfToppings` is defined in your header, but is *only* assigned a value once you enter the loop if `toppings == 1`

Later on when you calculate the `baseCost` you use the value of `numberOfToppings`, at this point in the code, the user could have opted to not have any toppings, and `numberOfToppings` has never been assigned an initial value.

To circumvent this, you should initialize your variables to the desired default value *0* in your header.

```
double numberOfToppings = 0;
```

The same applies to the others you mentioned, all for the same reason. Based on user input, those variables may never be initialized but you still try to use them in your final calculation; you should be initializing them all.

As a side note, you should learn to use the Auto Formatter within your IDE for better code readability.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise these variables with some default values when you declare them.

Your code was messy but these variables could be never set according to user input so basically you can't use a variable which not initialised.

As a best practice don't declare local variables before use, this can cause to increase their scope. You should declare and initialise it immediately when you need to use a variable.